# Verilog error: Range must be bounded by constant expressions

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, digital, digital-logic

I'm new to verilog and I am doing a project for my class. So here is my code:

```
wire [n-1:0] subcounter_of_counter;
reg [n-1:0] mask,free;
//subcounter_of_counter: dinei ena vector apo poious subcounter apoteleitai o counter(id)
always @(*) begin //command or id or mask or free or subcounter_of_counter
if (command==increment) begin
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i=i+1)begin
        if (i<id) begin
            subcounter_of_counter[i]=1'b0;
        end else if (i==id) begin
            subcounter_of_counter[i]=1'b1;
        end else begin
            if( (|mask[id+1:i]) || (|free[id+1:i]) ) begin
                subcounter_of_counter[i]=1'b0;
            end else begin
                subcounter_of_counter[i]=1'b1;
            end
        end
    end
end
end
```

And the error says *"the range must be bounded by constant expressions."*

Any ideas how else I could write it to do the same operation?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you will need to do is create a masked and shifted version of `mask` and `free`.

```
reg [n-1:0] mask,free,local_mask, local_free;
always @(*) begin //command or id or mask or free or subcounter_of_counter
if (command==increment) begin
    local_mask = mask & ((64'b1<<id+1)-1); // clear bits above id+1
    local_free = free & ((64'b1<<id+1)-1); // clear bits above id+1
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i=i+1)begin
        if (i<id) begin
            subcounter_of_counter[i]=1'b0;
        end else if (i==id) begin
            subcounter_of_counter[i]=1'b1;
        end else begin
            if( (|local_mask) || (|local_free) ) begin
                subcounter_of_counter[i]=1'b0;
            end else begin
                subcounter_of_counter[i]=1'b1;
            end
        end
    end
local_mask = local_mask >> 1; // clear bits below i
local_free = local_free >> 1;
end // for
end // always
```

I didn't try this code, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Comment: thanks a lot dave, i get your point.
your answer helped me a lot :)

Comment: one question, why do you subtract one from local_mask and local_free?

Comment: Where do you think I'm subtracting one from local_mask and local_free?

Comment: oh i got it. Dave you are brilliant, u know this? :P i mean i envy how you could just give a solution. I wonder if could ever reach at this point. I'm just starting with HDL design but i wish one day to be like you. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: well i want one last help, what im trying to do is for example i have the vector:
mask=   00001001001
if id=3 i want the output vector to be: out=00000111000
so what i want to do is when the out to give me 1 from the id of mask till before the first 1 it will discover. So if id=0 i would expect out=00000000111